# How to add hash character search to sphinx

Tags: sphinx, hashtag

I have done the following updates to sphinx to include a hash character in my search to no avail.

config file:
   source MY_SOURCE{
...
       sql_qudery_pre = SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=utf8
       sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
}

index MY_INDEX {
   path         = C:\Sphinx\data\MY_INDEX

...

```
  charset_type      = utf-8
  charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, a..z, +, #, U+002E
```

}

I then run indexer --rotate --all.  Please not that Sphinx is running as a Window's service.

When I run the following query, I get no results:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM MY_INDEX WHERE Match("#");
```

Can someone please look at this info and let me know what I am doing incorrectly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A single # in the config file signifies a comment, and so not seen, need to encode it `U+0023`.